# Bash: get json value

Tags: json, bash

sorry for simplicity, but I am new to bash.

I am curling a link that returns me json file:

```
$output=$(curl localhost:9000/user/1)
```

This returns me:

```
{"userId":"1", "username":"sam"}
```

How can echo username `sam`?

These didn't work:

```
echo $output.userId
echo $output["userId"]
```

Comment: Install the `jq` program, it's a JSON parser utility.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/):

```
jq .username <<<"$output"
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a simpler way to do it without jq?

Comment: Not a reliable, robust way that'll hold up to changes in the data format in the future.

Comment: got it, thanks @Charles Duffy

Comment: (If you can't install `jq`, you *can* get a JSON parser from somewhere else -- for instance, Python has a good one, and it's easy to have a shell function that asks Python to parse some JSON for you; there should already be Q&A entries in the knowledgebase describing how to do that).